# created_at attribute doesn't update when importing CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I tried to import a CSV file to my database. I need the app to 
use the exact created_at attribute from the CSV file, but it won't work.
I see only `Time.now`.

What am I doing wrong?

The CSV import code in the model:

```
  def self.import(file, current_user)
    allowed_attributes = [ "id","created_at","updated_at"]
    @current_user = current_user
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      energy = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      h1 = { "user_id" => @current_user.id }
      h2 = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      h3 = h1.merge(h2)
      energy.attributes = h3
      energy.save!
    end
  end
```

Comment: You'll have to explicitly set created_at. accessible_attributes does'nt have created_at.

Comment: set created_at `h3[:created_at] =  row["created_at"] #THE_TIME_FROM_CSV`

Comment: Please, do not down vote the question. I just wanted to figure it out. I would post a .csv table screenshot; however, I can't do it due to lack of reputation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible):

```
attr_accessible(*args) public
```

Specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment.

Mass-assignment will only set attributes in this list, to assign to the rest of attributes you can use direct writer methods.

You need to add to `attr_accessible` all the attributes you are willing to update, including `created_at`.